# WP Cron job every 1st and 15th of the month

Tags: cron, wp-cron, timestamp

Trying to set up custom schedules for WP Cron, knowing that they use an interval is it even possible to set up a cron job for every first of the month? As well as every fifteenth. This is what I have so far:

```
private function cron_schedules( $schedules ) {

    $midnight = strtotime( "midnight", current_time( 'timestamp' ) );
    $first = strtotime( 'first day of this month', $midnight );
    $fifteenth = $first + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60) * 2;

    $schedules['1st'] = array(
        'interval'  => $first,
        'display'   => __('1st of every month'),
    );

    $schedules['15th'] = array(
        'interval'  => $fifteenth,
        'display'   => __('15th of every month'),
    );

    $schedules['weekly'] = array(
        'interval'  => ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ),
        'display'   => __('Weekly'),
    );

    $schedules['biweekly'] = array(
        'interval'  => ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) * 2,
        'display'   => __('Biweekly'),
    );

    return $schedules;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wp_cron` operates on intervals and there is no interval that will hit exactly the first day and the 15th of every month.

You could run your `wp-cron` job every day and check the date, [similar to this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109438/21376) but with a simple callback like:

```
cron_callback_wpse_113675() {
  $date = date('d');
  if ('01' == $date || '15' == $date) {
    // run your function
  }
}
```

Or, use [`wp_schedule_single_event`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_single_event) with a more complicated callback. Something like this:

```
function cron_callback_v2_wpse_113675() {
  $date = date('d');
  if (!wp_next_scheduled(cron_callback_v2_wpse_113675)) {
    $date = ($date < 15) ? '15' : '01';
  }
  if ('01' == $date || '15' == $date) {
    // run your function
    switch ($date) {
      case '01' :
        wp_schedule_single_event( strtotime('+14 days',strtotime('first day of')), 'cron_callback_v2_wpse_113675' );
      break;
      case '15' :
        wp_schedule_single_event( strtotime('first day of'), 'cron_callback_v2_wpse_113675' );
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

<strike>Barely</strike> Completely untested. Possibly buggy. *Caveat emptor*. No refunds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I found this as well http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41541/schedule-event-every-second-thursday-of-the-month wondering if I can set up my own custom scheduler. What are your thoughts?

Comment: I have seen that 'transient' solution before but I don't see the advantage over using `wp_schedule_single_event` as above, assuming that untested code actually works. Maybe I am missing something though.

Comment: Testing your first example right now, I'll let you know how it goes. Just wanted to see your thoughts on the other post. Thanks.

Comment: Tested out and seems to working great so far. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think it's not necessary to run any job every day, but we can use `wp_schedule_single_event` and call it again when our function is finished to shedule the next job

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue but needed to fire an event on the last day of the month.  I figured out an alternate solution that would work for this and my issue.  Instead of modifying the schedules, I used the daily schedule to simply fire my monthly actions if necessary.

First I added code like this to my plugin activation to setup the daily check

```
function my_activation(){
    // Set the cron job for the monthly cron
    if( ! wp_next_scheduled ( 'maybe_monthly_cron' ) ) {
        // This will trigger an action that will fire the "monthly_cron" action on the last day of each month at 4:00 am UTC
        wp_schedule_event( strtotime('04:00:00'), 'daily', 'maybe_monthly_cron');
    }
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_activation' );
```

Then I added a job to run daily to see if it needed to fire the monthly cron

```
// Check if we need to fire the monthly cron action "monthly_cron"
function maybe_run_monthly_cron(){
    $now = strtotime();
    $this_day = date( 'j', $now );
    $days_this_month = date( 't', $now );
    if( $this_day == $days_this_month ){
        do_action( 'monthly_cron' );
    }
}
add_action( 'maybe_monthly_cron', 'maybe_run_monthly_cron' );
```

To adjust this to fire on the 1st & 15th, you could just adjust the code above to something like this:

```
// Check if we need to fire the monthly cron action "monthly_cron"
function maybe_run_monthly_cron(){
    $now = strtotime();
    $this_day = date( 'j', $now );
    if( in_array( $this_day, array( 1, 15 ) ) ){
        do_action( 'monthly_cron' );
    }
}
add_action( 'maybe_monthly_cron', 'maybe_run_monthly_cron' );
```

Then you can just use the "monthly_cron" action to perform your actions like this:

```
function my_monthly_cron(){
    // Execute monthly or bimonthly code here...
}
add_action( 'monthly_cron', 'my_monthly_cron' );
```